# sed insert line on first blank line after XXX

Tags: bash, sed

I am interactively editing my hosts file with a bash script. I need to insert a line in my hosts file. The line needs to be inserted on the first blank line after a specific comment. The content I am inserting is in a variable.

Here is what I tried ($NEWLINE is set previously):

`sed -i '# Insert New DNS / Virtualbox/$NEWLINE/g' /etc/hosts`

I get no error, but the line is not written. Any advice?

Comment: Please comment when you downvote. Let me know why??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose:

```
# Insert New DNS
```

is the line after which you want to insert at first empty line:

You can achieve this by the following command:

```
 sed -i '/# Insert New DNS/,/^$/s/^$/'"$NEWLINE"'/' /etc/hosts
```

The following will search for line numbers (addresses) in the file:

```
/# Insert New DNS/,/^$/
```

The following will replace the "empty line"

```
s/^$/'"$NEWLINE"'/
```

Comment: With `$NEWLINE` inside `'...'`, its value will not be expanded. You probably meant to write `sed -i '/# Insert New DNS/,/^$/s/^$/'"$NEWLINE"'/' /etc/hosts`